# Formula for $\Phi_{3p}(x)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

While I was experimenting with [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) , denoted as $\Phi_n(x)$ , I came up with the following formula for $\Phi_{3p}(x)$ , where $p$ is a prime number greater than $3$ :

> $$\Phi_{3p}(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\left(i+1-3\left\lfloor \frac{i+2}{3} \right\rfloor\right) \cdot \left(x^i+x^{2(p-1)-i}\right)-(-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{1}{3}\left(p-6\left\lfloor \frac{p}{6} \right\rfloor\right) \right\rfloor} \cdot x^{p-1}$$

I have [verified](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwtzkEKAyEMBdCzdJdkIupIZ1O8ipuhQsCpwbZgb98M7S6f_z6k9qFDjjtovnIMIbBUeL4PkBxYXWSQJbpEtfU-wMKKPiESzCLLLLASmEIniOjArvKT0aez2f5D9ZsBssGpL1l72z9765BIeSLbD48XqJnbF8mjKRU=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) this formula for $p \in [5,4999]$ .

**Question.** Is there an easy way to justify this formula?

Comment: Perhaps if you explained how you worked out the formula, it might help someone be able to explain why it holds

Comment: @P [As is stated here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Easy_cases_for_computation), we have
$$
\Phi_{3p}(x) = \frac{\Phi_p(x^3)}{\Phi_p(x)} = \frac{\Phi_3(x^p)}{\Phi_3(x)}.
$$
I suspect that this can be used to derive your formula.

Comment: @P The summation formula is difficult to parse. Could you please write it in the form
$$
\Phi_{3p}(x) = a_0(x^0 + x^{2(p-1)}) + a_1(x^1 + x^{2(p-1)-1}) + \cdots?
$$

Comment: @Moko19 Looking at few cyclotomic polynomials of the given form with small $p$ I noticed a pattern in forming of polynomial terms.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Both $\Phi_{p}(x)$ and $\Phi_{2p}(x)$ are  expressible in the form of the single sum , that's why I wanted to express $\Phi_{3p}(x)$ in the similar form

Answer (score 0):

For prime $p>3$,
$$\Phi_{3p}(x)=\frac{1+x^p+x^{2p}}{1+x+x^2}=\frac{1-x+x^p-x^{p+1}+x^{2p}-x^{2p+1}}{1-x^3}.$$If $p\equiv1\pmod 3$ then
\begin{align}
\Phi_{3p}(x)&=\frac{1-x^{2p+1}}{1-x^3}
-\frac{x-x^p}{1-x^3}-\frac{x^{p+1}-x^{2p}}{1-x^3}\\
&=(1+x^3+\cdots+x^{2p-2})-(x+x^4+\cdots+x^{p-3})-(x^{p+1}+x^{p+4}+\cdots+x^{2p-3})
\end{align}
and if $p\equiv2\pmod 3$ then
\begin{align}
\Phi_{3p}(x)&=\frac{1-x^{p+1}}{1-x^3}
-\frac{x-x^{2p}}{1-x^3}+\frac{x^p-x^{2p+1}}{1-x^3}\\
&=(1+x^3+\cdots+x^{p-2})-(x+x^4+\cdots+x^{2p-3})+(x^p+x^{p+3}+\cdots+x^{2p-2}).
\end{align}

Do these accord with your formula?

Comment: I think they do accord.